# Xampp reinstallation issue

Tags: mysql, apache, xampp

I have uninstalled Xampp And installed again with new PHP version. I copied back htdocs folder to the xampp folder. After reinstallation I cannot get to my old mysql database. When I type in localhost/.../index.php in order to get to the main php file, I get "Page not found". I had run Xampp Control Panel as an administrator and started Apache and MySQL servers and services. I am using Windows 7.

Comment: Did you backup your databases before uninstalling XAMPP?

Comment: I just copied the whole htdocs folder.

Comment: But forgot that you needed your old databases as well?

Comment: Should I understand that my database is gone? What about the "Page not found" part of the question?

Comment: Well if you deleted the old XAMPP folder yes it looks like you lost your databases. If you are using WordPress or something similiar then that would probably also explain the `page not found` as well

Comment: OK. Just for the sake of future - how can I backup the database, as I am a greenhorn in programming? The second question, _even more important for me at the moment_ - **how can I reactivate this virtual (PHPmyAdmin/Apache) server** - what I mean is the localhost, it does not respond to the setup from index.php, for which it did before the Xampp was reinstalled -> ->

Comment: -> -> If it helps, I was following all the steps shown in this video: [(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DHUxnUX7Y2Y&t=1015s)] - before the Xampp reinstallation I went through the whole tutorial on my computer and everything worked fine, after the reinstallation **I got stuck at 10:15 minute of this tutorial, I get "Page Not Found"**. Please help :(

Comment: No one is going to watch a dupious video for 10 minutes to see where you may have gone wrong

Comment: What would you recommend then?

Comment: OK. I have updated my knowledge in terms of how to backup the database :)

Comment: In terms of the second question- an issue with localhost, I see that the problem is with the 'require' in the index.php file. There are 3 'require' statemnts in that file and 2 of them related to "Hello world" type of message for localhost. When I delete one statement, the other one works and on the contrary. Thank for help anyway!